# How to check if Cell values balance each other

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to Create a Formula that checks 4 Cells next to each other if they have the same number once positive and once negative see in the example:

[image: Example to recreate Sheet]

If the formula sees there is a Plus 50 and a Minus 50 its has to colour the cell on the right side or the cells with the numbers blue.

The list is a inventory of multiple stores if one store sells alot of that product and may run out they ask another store to restock the product. Sometimes they forget to send a note. This List is supposed to make the control as easy as possible.

I expect the formula to color the cell on the right side of the list to be colored blue if 2 of the cells have the same value in plus and minus.

I tried to use  cell formatting rules but its not possible to do it with that.

Another Example since people seem to have trouble understanding what the formula should do:

I marked every cell blue like the formula should and yellow colored value is the reason.

[image]

Comment: I don't see why the same value in stock should be needed. Wouldn't it make sense that if Stock 3 has 100 items and if Stock 1 has -20 that they send 20 even if it is not the same amount they have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, using conditional formatting, using this formula (just for the first row):

```
=OR(A1+B1=0;B1+C1=0;C1+D1=0)
```

This formula checks if the sum of two adjacent cells equals zero, which is another way of saying that they should have the same value, but opposite signs.

Obviously, you might consider changing this formula, e.g.:
Instead of:

```
A1+B1=0
```

you put:

```
AND(A1+B1=0;A1<>0)
```

When the sum of two values equals zero and at least one of them is not zero, then both are not zero.

All this together in one formula yields the following:

```
=OR(AND(A1+B1=0;A1<>0);AND(B1+C1=0;B1<>0);AND(C1+D1=0;C1<>0))
```

Use such a formula in the conditional formatting of cell `E1`, and apply this for all cells in `E` column.

Comment: This Formula works but it marks every cell with no differences as true by only that result i cant see which cells have 2 numbers that equal each other

Comment: @Cedric: I adapted my answer accordingly, I just merged the `AND()`-clause in the formula, as I mentioned, and it seems to work: I set the values 1, 2, -4, 4 and the formula gives `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Row As Long, Column As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    'Let us assume that we use Sheet1 & columns A to F
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For Row = 2 To 100 ' <- Let us assume that data starts in row 2 and ends in row 100
            Set rng = .Range("B" & Row & ":E" & Row)

            For Column = 2 To 6
                If .Cells(Row, Column).Value <> 0 Then
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, (-1 * .Cells(Row, Column).Value)) > 0 Then
                        .Range("F" & Row).Interior.Color = vbBlue
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next Column
        Next Row

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion the script is marking the side if the value is 0 in every cell not +50 and -50 or +10 and -10

Comment: if you add together +50, -50, +10,10 is equal to 0

Comment: Yes you are correct but i need the cell to be blue if 2 of the 4 cells have the same value just in negative and minus so i can see the product from that place went there as in my example

Comment: Ok, if column A has a value must have the negatice one in column D and if column B has a value column C will have the negative?

Comment: I added a screenshot that should clarify the purpose of the formula, the positive and negative could be in any of the 4 cells maybe a and d or c and a ....

Comment: Thanks alot this works Great  if i could i would mark your answer as correct too

Comment: @Cedric glad to hear that my answer helps you. i think you can only mark one answer as the correct. You have mark my answer as correct at first place but then you remove it.

Comment: Yes im sorry about it but i am using the excel in my worksheet because its a bit less complicated to use but as i said both answers work if i could i would give you both the correct one :(